# Finding the length of the side of a triangle, given the lengths of the other two sides.

Tags: geometry

$ABC$ is a triangle with $AB=86$ and $AC=97$. A circle is drawn with $AB$ as radius which cuts $BC$ at $B$ and $X$ such that length of $BX$ and $XC$ is an integer. Find the length of $BC$.

Please help me out with this question.

Comment: Maybe you can draw a picture and see what you you can deduce after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $ABX$ and $AXC$ will be right-angled triangles, with $\angle AXB$ and $\angle AXC$ being $90$ degree. Let $BX=x, CX=y$ and $AX=z$. Then,
$$y^2+z^2=97^2\\and\\x^2+z^2=86^2$$
Subtract them to get
$$(y+x)(y-x)=97^2-86^2=11\cdot183=1\cdot3\cdot11\cdot61$$
$y-x$ can attain the values $1, 3, 11$ and $33$. It can't attain others because it can't be greater than $y+x$. If $y-x=1$, $y+x=2013$. But, $AB+AC$ should be more than $BC$, which isn't the case. So, $y-x=1$ is rejected. Similarly, $3$ and $11$ won't be acceptable either. Hence, $y-x=33\implies BC=x+y=61$.